# Hadoop/Hive : Loading data from .csv on a local machine

Tags: sql, csv, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive

As this is coming from a newbie...

I had Hadoop and Hive set up for me, so I can run Hive queries on my computer accessing data on AWS cluster.
Can I run Hive queries with .csv data stored on my computer, like I did with MS SQL Server?

How do I load .csv data into Hive then? What does it have to do with Hadoop and which mode I should run that one?

What settings I should care about so that if I did something wrong I can always go back and run queries on Amazon without compromising what was set up for me earlier?

Answer (score 58):

Let me work you through the following simple steps:

Steps:

First, create a table on hive using the field names in your csv file. Lets say for example, your csv file contains three fields (id, name, salary) and you want to create a table in hive called "staff". Use the below code to create the table in hive.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE Staff (id int, name string, salary double) row format delimited fields terminated by ',';
```

Second, now that your table is created in hive, let us load the data in your csv file to the "staff" table on hive.

```
hive>  LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/yourcsvfile.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Staff;
```

Lastly, display the contents of your "Staff" table on hive to check if the data were successfully loaded

```
hive> SELECT * FROM Staff;
```

Thanks.

Comment: There should be double quotes here
`terminated by ",";`

Comment: Setting delimiter during table creation is not intuitive. I expect to be able to set delimiter at the time of loading data from particular file. What if new data file has different delimiter?

Comment: can i try this  from any other system, not from cluster or edge node? I mean any other linux box not part of hdfs cluster. If yes, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: is overwrite into table required?

Answer (score 17):

if you have a hive setup you can put the local dataset directly using Hive load command  in hdfs/s3.

You will need to use "Local" keyword when writing your load command.

Syntax for hiveload command

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)]
```

Refer below link for more detailed information.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual%20DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables

Answer (score 15):

There is another way of enabling this,

1. use hadoop hdfs -copyFromLocal to copy the .csv data file from your local computer to somewhere in HDFS, say '/path/filename'
2. enter Hive console, run the following script to load from the file to make it as a Hive table. Note that '\054' is the ascii code of 'comma' in octal number, representing fields delimiter.

---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table name (foo INT, bar STRING)
 COMMENT 'from csv file'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '/path/filename';
```

Comment: Does the field delimiter need to be speicified in octal? Why not just use ',' ?

Comment: John, yes, octal 054 is just ascii ',' and Hive support use ',' directly

Answer (score 9):

For csv file formate data will be in below format

```
"column1", "column2","column3","column4"
```

And if we will use field terminated by ',' then each column will get values like below.

```
"column1"    "column2"     "column3"     "column4"
```

also if any of the column value has `comma` as value then it will not work at all .

So the correct way to create a table would be by using OpenCSVSerde

```
create table tableName (column1 datatype, column2 datatype , column3 datatype , column4 datatype)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE ;
```

Comment: This has the downside of saving all columns as Strings, no matter how your table is defined.

Answer (score 6):

You may try this,
Following are few examples on how files are generated. 
Tool -- https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvtohive/?source=directory

1. Select a CSV file using Browse and set hadoop root directory ex: /user/bigdataproject/
2. Tool Generates Hadoop script with all csv files and following is a sample of 
   generated Hadoop script to insert csv into Hadoop

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -v

   hadoop fs -put ./AllstarFull.csv /user/bigdataproject/AllstarFull.csv
   hive -f ./AllstarFull.hive
   ```

   hadoop fs -put ./Appearances.csv /user/bigdataproject/Appearances.csv
   hive -f ./Appearances.hive

   hadoop fs -put ./AwardsManagers.csv /user/bigdataproject/AwardsManagers.csv
   hive -f ./AwardsManagers.hive
3. Sample of generated Hive scripts

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS lahman;

   USE lahman;

   CREATE TABLE AllstarFull (playerID string,yearID string,gameNum string,gameID string,teamID string,lgID string,GP string,startingPos string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

   LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/bigdataproject/AllstarFull.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE AllstarFull;

   SELECT * FROM AllstarFull;
   ```

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You can load local CSV file to Hive only if:

1. You are doing it from one of the Hive cluster nodes.
2. You installed Hive client on non-cluster node and using `hive` or `beeline` for upload.