# Hive table field is delimited by '¬' hive does not accept this character

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive

The data i have is delimited by '¬' when i try using it in create table i get error as invalid character. i tried using it's unicode version '\U00AC' but no use all record gets ingested in first field. in unix this character '¬' is displayed as ï¿½.
Could anyone guide me on this as to what to use in the field terminated by section.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
CONTACT_RECORD_ID    string,
ACCOUNT    string,
CUST    string,
NUMBER    string,
NUMBER1    string,
NUMBER2    string,
NUMBER3    string,
NUMBER4    string,
NUMBER5    string,
NUMBER6    string,
NUMBER7    string,
LIST    string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¬';
```

Comment: In whatever displays `ï¿½` you need to change the text encoding settings.

Comment: On Linux, what does the `file xyz.txt` command show? I.e. which encoding? Hadoop expects UTF-8 by default.

Comment: yes bang on its encoded as ISO-8859 text any solution to this buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with this DDL.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
CONTACT_RECORD_ID    string,
ACCOUNT    string,
CUST    string,
NUMBER    string,
NUMBER1    string,
NUMBER2    string,
NUMBER3    string,
NUMBER4    string,
NUMBER5    string,
NUMBER6    string,
NUMBER7    string,
LIST    string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('empty.string.null'='true','field.delim'='\0AC','serialization.format'='\0AC','serialization.null.format'='')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

Comment: ty tried it but didn't solve the problem. all data in first column

Comment: output is like this 1ï¿½0000000000000010792ï¿½0000000000000549223ï¿½HFBlHgUUmGrCdï¿½HaNlzg0tEï¿½4Gï¿½HFNï¿½Hï¿½Xï¿½ï¿½ï¿½93aï¿½HFNBd2htï¿½QB3aï¿½HFNBughjkL4ï¿½u    NULL    NULLNULL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

Comment: Can you verify the file contains the ¬ as delimiter.Please use "cat <path to data file in local> | grep ¬ "

Answer (score 0):

if you have data in csv format, you can use this tool as in [Hadoop/Hive : Loading data from .csv on a local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320611/hadoop-hive-loading-data-from-csv-on-a-local-machine/31386508#31386508) to easily export data into Hadoop.